# What is auxiliary loss in Character-level Transformer model?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, loss-function, transformer

I am reading [Character-Level Language Modeling with Deeper Self-Attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04444) from Rami Al-Rfou. In the second page, they had mentioned about Auxiliary Losses which can speed-up the model convergence and as an additional regularizer. They said they had 3 kinds of auxiliary losses:

1. Auxiliary losses at intermediate sequence positions
2. Auxiliary losses from intermediate hidden representations
3. Auxiliary losses at target positions multiple steps.

However, I cannot find any information or reference explaining auxiliary losses. I would like to know:

- What is auxiliary losses? Is it an [unsupervised prediction model using part of the data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00144)?
- How can I calculate the auxiliary losses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auxiliary losses are additional terms added to your global loss to induce learning further upstream in your model and can be seen as a way to combat vanishing gradients.

An early reference would be how [Google's Inception model uses auxiliary classifiers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842.pdf). The general idea is that you take an intermediate output of your model and use it as the prediction in a separate loss function. So during training, your model is acting as both a global model (all parameters subject to that final global loss) and a model composed of sub-models with specific terms applying exclusively to your auxiliary tasks.

In practical terms, you can follow [this example](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-optimize-inception-model-with-auxiliary-classifiers/7958). If the link ever dies, here's a generic view:

```
# let's say we have two auxiliary losses, and thus two auxiliary outputs
final_task_prediction, predictions = model.forward(x)

global_loss = loss(final_task_prediction, y)
intermediate_loss_1 = aux_loss_1(predictions[0], aux_y_1)
intermediate_loss_2 = aux_loss_2(predictions[1], aux_y_2)

# can weight auxiliary losses however we choose
total_loss = global_loss + .4*intermediate_loss_1 + .8*intermediate_loss_2
total_loss.backward()
```

As an example, say we have an input sequence **ABCDEF**. To quickly run through the auxiliary losses in the Al-Rfou et al. paper

- *Multiple positions* works as an auxiliary task of "given A, predict B, then given B (and our internal memory of A), predict C" (etc)
- *Intermediate hidden representations* works the same as multiple positions, except intermediate layers also get their own loss terms
- *Multiple predictions* breaks the target prediction sequence into multiple subsequences, so our auxiliary task is "given A predict B,C ; given B, predict C,D" (etc)

Hope this helps!